# Changing the default delimiter with acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

The default delimiter in the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem is a comma. I'd like to change this to a space throughout my Rails 3 application. For example, tag_list should be assigned like this:

```
object.tag_list = "tagone tagtwo tagthree"
```

rather than like this:

```
object.tag_list = "tagone, tagtwo, tagthree"
```

What is the best way to go about changing the delimiter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need define the delimiter class variable in ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList class

In an initializer add that :

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList.delimiter = ' '
```

Comment: in the newest version: ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ' '

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go hacking around inside acts-as-taggable-on, just create another method on the class that implements it:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

  def human_tag_list
    self.tag_list.gsub(', ', ' ')
  end

  def human_tag_list= list_of_tags
    self.tag_list = list_of_tags.gsub(' ', ',')
  end
end

MyClass.get(1).tag_list # => "tagone, tagtwo, tagthree"
MyClass.get(1).human_tag_list # => "tagone and tagtwo and tagthree"
MyClass.get(1).human_tag_list = "tagone tagtwo tagthree"
```

Comment: This won't work for my application, since the user will be assigning the tag_list though a text field (e.g. `<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>`), and I want for them to be able to type spaces instead of commas to separate the tags. But this a good solution for handling the presentation of the tags after they've been created.