# How do I use tag names that contain commas with acts-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts-as-taggable-on in my application and I want to be able to use tag names that contain commas such as "Ben, Jerry." However, when I put something like '"Ben, Jerry", Bob, Bill' in the tag list, it gets returned as "Ben, Jerry, Bob, Bill."

If I go into the database and manually change the name of one of the tags to "Ben, Jerry" then when I open the object, the tag list shows up as '"Ben, Jerry", Bob, Bill' but if I save that it gets returned as "Ben, Jerry, Bob, Bill"

Am I doing something wrong or is acts-as-taggable-on not capable of saving tags with commas by default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591648/changing-the-default-delimiter-with-acts-as-taggable-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your delimiter to a semi-colon:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList.delimiter = '; '
```